# Homepage help laravel

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

Hi im new to all this website stuff and been trying to remove two sections off my homepage i have been trying all day and keep messing it up i want to remove

[section 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJFcx.png)

[section 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3pIS.png)

here is the code in my pastebin https://pastebin.com/h9Z60HSX where do i start? or if someone is kind enough to help me out removing it i would really appreciate it
my site is [www.coralzauctions.co.uk](http://www.coralzauctions.co.uk) `code`

Comment: you should start reading stackoverflow rules, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You've been messing up how? What have you tried?

Comment: Any code i remove scrambles the homepage and looks a mess

Comment: Have you tried checking which elements you need to remove using inspecting the website by right clicking and using inspect element?

Comment: Yes been trying that with firefox, there is a page editor within the script controle panel that doesnt work so im stuck and might have to hire someone to do it

Comment: Could you please include your images and code in the question?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with laravel and should be closed. Anyways, the elements you are looking to remove are the **third** and **fifth** `<section>` (With everything in between of course). There are 5 `<section>` elements on your html, so finding them shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a general question, here's some general answers to your questions:

> where do i start?

I would start by reading the Laravel documentation. It's a quick read and if you read it from beginning to end in a sitting, you'll likely have a good general undestanding of what tools you have to work with. Here's the link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation

> trying to remove two sections off my homepage i have been trying all
> day and keep messing it up i want to remove

To remove visual code, check out the documentation regarding Views and then Blade:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views

In those docs, you'll see how html is added (and removed).

And from your comments:

> Any code i remove scrambles the homepage and looks a mess

You might also try then a more beginner route such as Codecademy or an online course on html basiscs. If you can't design what you have in your mind, practice is going to be key and learning the basics of html will help a lot. Laravel is something you should pick up once you have some basics of html, css, and php.

And as far as StackOverflow goes, the most important thing if you have a question relating to your code is to post your code. In this case you would want to paste the contents of your view file. The StackOverflow rules will help you write an effective question, and to properly format your question so that we can read it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove/edit page content is to open dev tools on the page you want to edit and then click on the section you want to remove/edit and see the corresponding code in the dev tools.

For eg with http://www.coralzauctions.co.uk/ open in a tab in Chrome right click on "How it works" and select `Inspect` from the context menu - it will highlight the `<h2>` in dev tools then look up to get the `<section>` tag and collapse by clicking on it. Right click on the collapsed `<section>` tag and select `Copy > Copy OuterHTML` from the context menu. This will give you the code for the entire section.

If you just want to remove it you can see that within the `<div data-name="Main Wrapper">` it's the third `<section>` tag find the corresponding tag in your actual code and delete/remove the code in your editor and save.

The process remains same when using Firefox except that when you right click on "How It Works" the context menu will have `Inspect Element` instead of `Inspect`

If you need any help in terms of pointers to resources which will help you get comfortable with the basics you can get in touch neerav[at]thinkstudeo[dot]com

Like @Citizen has pointed out you need to learn the basics by taking some basic courses.

Happy coding!